# firing a query based on the if statement in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to perform a query based on the condition from a variable.
but I can't use case structure
because the column I want to be included in the query is in a "GROUP BY" statement.

```
    SELECT COUNT (rs.id), 
        c.title "City", 
        date '{{ Initial date }}' + interval '1 month' AS "Date"
FROM rooms_reservations rs
    LEFT JOIN lead_lead ll ON rs.journey_id = ll.id
    LEFT JOIN cities c ON ll.city_id = c.id
  WHERE rs.start_date <= date '{{ Initial date }}'+ interval '1 month'
    AND c.title = '{{ City }}'
GROUP BY "Date",
         c.title -- <- the column appear in a group by statement
```

- {{ City }} is a redash variable

I need to the results to be shown for all cities, so it can be queried by this query

```
    SELECT COUNT (rs.id), 
        --c.title "City", 
        date '{{ Initial date }}' + interval '1 month' AS "Date"
FROM rooms_reservations rs
    LEFT JOIN lead_lead ll ON rs.journey_id = ll.id
    LEFT JOIN cities c ON ll.city_id = c.id
  WHERE rs.start_date <= date '{{ Initial date }}'+ interval '1 month'
    --AND c.title = '{{ City }}' -- <- ex. NYC, WAS, BOS, etc.
GROUP BY "Date" --,
         --c.title
```

So I would like to have some thing like this:
if condition = 'all_cities' then execute 2nd query
if condition != 'all_cities' then execute 1st query.

Is it possible?
I use read only replica of postgres db

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE expression. Replace `<condition>` with a real one

```
SELECT COUNT (rs.id), 
        CASE WHEN <condition> THEN c.title ELSE 'ALL' END "City", 
        date '{{ Initial date }}' + interval '1 month' AS "Date"
FROM rooms_reservations rs
LEFT JOIN lead_lead ll ON rs.journey_id = ll.id
LEFT JOIN cities c ON ll.city_id = c.id
WHERE rs.start_date <= date '{{ Initial date }}'+ interval '1 month'
    AND c.title = '{{ City }}'
GROUP BY "Date",
     CASE WHEN <condition> THEN c.title ELSE 'ALL' END
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8a3767b8ee77888540f065853f6050ec)